# split data frame by all columns and insert in to a list of data frames

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, subset

Is there a way to split a data frame in a list of data frames per column, and then adding a counter or something to column names e.g. ab_a, cd_a

some random data for an example

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'ab': [1, 3, 1, 4, -1, 1],
                     'cd': [1, 1, -0, 1, -0],
                     'ef': [1, 2, 1, 1, 2],
                     'gh': [1, 4, 2, 3, 1]})
```

The expected output would look something like

```
lst = [ab \ 
1
2
1
4 
-1 
1,

cd \
1
1
-0
1
-0,

ef\
1 
2
1
1
2,

gh\
1
4
2
3
1]
```

where you can access each element within the list with e.g. lst[0] - which would output the column ab as a single data frame

```
**ab**
1
2
1
4
-1
1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you edit your post and put there expected output?

Comment: @AndrejKesely sure - hope that did not make it more confusing...Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: @AndrejKesely This is throwing the following error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_frame'

Comment: Is your variable `data` a DataFrame? You can try to remove `.to_frame()`

Comment: @AndrejKesely yes i figured that out after! works perfectly thanks so much :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.pop` and then `.to_frame()`. For example:

```
lst = [data.pop(col).to_frame() for col in data.columns]
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```py
[   ab
0   1
1   3
2   1
3   4
4  -1,    cd
0   1
1   1
2   0
3   1
4   0,    ef
0   1
1   2
2   1
3   1
4   2,    gh
0   1
1   4
2   2
3   3
4   1]
```

Then you can do:

```
# print first dataframe
print(lst[0])
```

Prints:

```
   ab
0   1
1   3
2   1
3   4
4  -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use to_dict(orient='list') -

```
result = list(df.to_dict(orient='list').values())
```

Output -

```
print(result[1])
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```